# Using die() after mail() causes email not to send

Tags: php

I have the code below and the redirect works.  However when I have the die() command at the bottom the email doesn't get sent. The email goes fine without the die() command.

Is there a way I can stop the php script continuing without stopping the email from working?

```
$to      = 'hello@nospam.com';
$subject = "Test Subject";
$message = "Test Message";
$headers = 'From: robocop@nospam.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: robocop@nosopam.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
header('Location:http://nospam.com/home/bouncer.php');
die();
```

Comment: You can try the exit() command, to see if it works.

Comment: I doubt this is the real issue, I often send a header and then use exit and don't have this issue

Comment: Yes, I have tested the same code with and without the die command.

Comment: Will try exit(); and see what happens. Could be a server configuration issue.

Comment: Did you verify if the header is generated for the page in the `die()` case?

Answer (score -3):

Try this for testing. I don't think that there are really such problem.

```
$to      = 'hello@nospam.com';
$subject = "Test Subject";
$message = "Test Message";
$headers = 'From: robocop@nospam.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: robocop@nosopam.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
    header('Location:http://nospam.com/home/bouncer.php');
} else {
    echo "Fail";
}
die(); // and use for also exit(); for testing
```

That's very interesting if it is real problem.